# part of the deserialized response is null

Tags: java, spring

The response from postman is

```
{
    "relation": [
        {
            "trans_id": 1,
            "data": {
                "PLC_id": 1,
                "temp_id": 1,
                "sla_id": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The way to get a response is

```
Mono<ClientResponse> response = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .build()
                .post()
                .uri("/sync")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .syncBody("{\"id\":1}")
                .exchange();
Info result = response.block().bodyToMono(Info.class).block();
```

But the result is like

```
Info(relation=[Trans(trans_id=1, data=PLC(PLC_id=null, temp_id=1, sla_id=1))])
```

The POJO PLC class is

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class PLC {
    private Integer PLC_id;
    private Integer temp_id;
    private Integer sla_id;
}
```

The spelling is checked several times, they are identical.
So why the `PLC_id` is null? What could be the problem?

My problem is different from
[Part of JSON response from server is returning null: Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44602128/1278112)
It's missing a key, while I have the key but with null value.

Comment: add your relation class too.

Comment: Can you add the generated lombok code? I suspect naming the field with an upper case letter caused something to be generated weird.

Comment: Otherwise, try adding a getter/setter manually

Comment: @orirab I think the root cause is not related to that part, see my answer.

Comment: It probably is, b.c. you have a private field so the only way to get to it is throught the getter/setter, so their naming is essentially the same thing as your answer, so I'm glad you solved it :)

Answer (score 3):

Enlighten by my coworker. Change the json response `PLC_id` to lowercase and it works fine.
So I searched something related to `json uppercase`, find the following question is most related to my situation.
[Spring REST consuming JSON uppercase vs lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890398/spring-rest-consuming-json-uppercase-vs-lowercase)

so one way is to change the response body.
Another is to

> You can use @JsonProperty annotation to override the variable name.
>
> ```
> @JsonProperty("phone")   
> public String PHONE;
> ```

There are also other related questions, mainly about case problem.

[Is there any way to create JSON object with keys as upper case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403133/is-there-any-way-to-create-json-object-with-keys-as-upper-case)
[How to convert all keys in JSON response to uppercase? (JAVA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677874/how-to-convert-all-keys-in-json-response-to-uppercase-java)
[Jackson - Java bean to JSON string : uppercase variable converted into lowercase in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678583/jackson-java-bean-to-json-string-uppercase-variable-converted-into-lowercase)
[Jackson - converting java object to json - Need all key keys to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049174/jackson-converting-java-object-to-json-need-all-key-keys-to-upper-case)
[Is there any way to create JSON object with keys as upper case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403133/is-there-any-way-to-create-json-object-with-keys-as-upper-case)